# Nav menu category links not showing

Tags: categories, menus

I am new to wordpress and have a project where I have show nav menu category links like this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'menu right'));
```

After adding a new category in the admin, the new category link is not showing in the menu. What should I do about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `wp_nav_menu` is a manually created menu - WordPress doesn't create it for you. If you want to keep using this function, you can go to either Appearance > Menus or Appearance > Customize > Menus, add links to the menu, and check the "primary" theme location under Display Location.

However - if you're just wanting to show category links, it's better to use one of the built-in options so that you don't have to manually add each category and keep them updated.

Option 1: create a sidebar and use the built-in "Categories" widget.

Option 2: pure code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'parent' => 0
  );
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a><br/>';
}
?>
```